# Using XSL transformations with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt

Does jQuery support XSL transformations of XML? If so how do I use it?

I have bespoke code that does this, but would rather use jQuery if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project [AJAXSLT](http://code.google.com/p/ajaxslt/) that "*is an implementation of XSLT in JavaScript. Because XSLT uses XPath, it is also an implementation of XPath that can be used independently of XSLT.*" Someone called Chainfire has written a [jQuery Plugin](http://www.jongma.org/webtools/jquery/xslt/) for this library. I haven't used them myself, so can't comment on how well they work.

Comment: So now way of doing it natively?